# Understanding how Hue in ColorFunction cycles through colors

Tags: plotting, color

When I use

`Plot[Exp[x], {x, -1, 1}, ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Hue[x]]]`

the output is acurve with colors cycling once from red to red. But when I do

`Plot[m - m*Log[m], {m, Exp[-1], Exp[1]}, ColorFunction -> Function[{m, b}, Hue[Log[m]]]]`

the output is a curve with colors cycling 4 or so times through the color wheel.

But, if `m` is ranging from `Exp[-1]` to `Exp[1]` in the second example, that would mean `Log[m]` is ranging from `-1` to `1`, which *should* mean that `Hue[Log[m]]` should go through the color wheel just as many times as `Hue[x]` does as `x` ranges from `-1` to `1`, but that's not what I see. What am I misunderstanding, and how do I fix this?

If it isn't clear, $b=m-m\ln m$ is (minus) the Legendre transform of $y=e^x$. The variables are all related by the slope-intercept formula $y=mx+b$ and slope $m=dy/dx$. Thus, every point on one graph should correspond to a point on the other. Ultimately, I'd like to attach some (monochromatic) tangent line segments (which match the color of the points they are tangent to) as a next step.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the arguments to `ColorFunction` are rescaled to be between 0 and 1.

In theory the curve should go through the color cycle an infinite number of times, since $\log(x)$ goes to $-\infty$ as $x$ goes to zero.  In practice the resolution of the plot isn't sufficient to achieve that.

If you set the option `ColorFunctionScaling -> False`, then the color function will use the original, unscaled values, and go through the color cycle twice (-1 to 0, and 0 to 1.)